# How to enable WAL (write ahead log) in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, wal

I currently have two different processes, one process writes into a database and the other one reads and updates the records in the database that were inserted by the first process. Every time I try to start both processes concurrently the database gets locked, makes sense. Due to simultaneous read and write. I came across WAL, but haven't been able to come across any example as to how to enable WAL in a c++ code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does SQLite allow concurrent access from *different* processes? I thought it was locked to do that within one process only. If you need a more robust database, consider Postgres or something explicitly designed for concurrent, multi-process access.

Comment: @tadman: Looks like SQLite can use shared memory. Postgres can work across different _computers_. That's still an issue with SQLite.

Comment: @MSalters I believe concurrency was something achievable using write ahead logging. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I'm not sure about the concurrency facilities available between processes both accessing the same database. In my experience SQLite performs very well with one process, but tends to under-perform when there's contention for the same resource.

Answer (score 0):

To activate it, as per [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) you just need to run the following statement:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL
```

This is persistent and only needs to be applied once.